# displaying an image fom mysql imageblob field onto a page using php

Tags: php, mysql

am new to php and am trying to output data from mysql database to a page.the text and numbers are printed on the page correctly but the image is not all i see is `��� �������� �w� ��|�PF��0100�V����h � I`.can anyone show me how to output an image onto page using php.

below is the code am using

```
<?php

    $username = "egesachi_baby";
    $password = "babyclass" ;
    $database = "egesachi_babyclass";
    $server = "localhost";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database)or die ("cannot connect");

    if ($db_found) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM baby";
        $result= mysql_query($sql);

        while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $db_field['NO']."<br>";
            echo $db_field['Name']."<br>";
            echo $db_field['Age']."<br>";
            echo  $db_field['photo']."<br>";
        }

        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
    else {
        print "database not found";
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }            
?>
```

Comment: How did you store the image in your database? With base64 encoding?

Comment: You will have to use this thing called HTML.

Answer (score 1):

you need to base64_encode your image data and know the image-type (gif, png or whatever).

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($db_field['photo'])?>"/>
```

Comment: still not working. the images are jpeg and are stored as mediumblob.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content of `$db_field['photo']`.

If it's base64 encoded data, something like this (if it's a jpeg):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $db_field['photo'] . '" />';
```

But it really all boils down to what `$db_field['photo']` contains. Can you give us an output sample?

Comment: the $db_field['photo'] is a mediumblob and it contains jpeg images

Comment: the code you provide still doesnt work.the $db_field['photo'] is a mediumblob and it contains jpeg images

Comment: Well, mediumblob is just a database type, and does not say anything about how the image data is stored. Is is stored as base64, binary, etc? You say it contains "jpeg images", but in what format (base64, binary, etc - not the database format) is the jpeg stored?